# Where to apply manual delay in character LCD

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, timing, waveform, character-lcd

I went to http://www.elm-chan.org/docs/lcd/hd44780_e.html in an attempt to find out how to make an LCD module work with the shortest timings. While the site does help with the initialization of the LCD, I feel as if it is not helping me enough.

Various sources state that for each LCD command or data processed, there is roughly a 40uS to 1.7mS delay before the command is complete.

The website mentions that I could poll the busy flag on the LCD but that would be too long of a delay (Its mentioned under the CPU load heading on the site).

So what I want to do is create a fixed delay in software so that the software continues to function even if the LCD gets disconnected from the circuit during operation.

The question is, where exactly do I implement the long microsecond delay in the code?

Do I insert the delay after I set enable to high (where green question mark is) or do I insert the delay after I set enable to low (where blue question mark is)?

I think its the latter, but I want to make sure.

[image: LCD timing]

Comment: For most operations you need both, before and after. And for some operations you need at least 1.52 ms

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at the datasheet for the LCD module, not at a typical application.

Anywhere the datasheet says you must meet a minimum delay time you need to make sure that you meet that delay. For the example timing diagram you provide, it looks like enable must be high for **at least** 450ns and its period must be **at least** 1000ns. You also need to make sure you meet the setup **and** hold times for R/S, RW, and DATA.
Depending on how fast your processor can toggle a GPIO line you may need several short delays in the software.

Comment: I should be able to meet minimum delays easy. I'm using an AT89S52 with a 20Mhz crystal attached, so each instruction will execute at 0.54uS minimum, so if anything I could get away with a couple nop's

Answer (score -1):

> Various sources state that for each LCD command or data processed, there is roughly a 40uS to 1.7mS delay before the command is complete.
>
> The question is, where exactly do I implement the long microsecond delay in the code?

The HD44780 and its clones will read the data/command in when the Enable (E) pin goes from high to low. That is the way you tell the LCD to process the command. The 1 millisecond delay should be there. That's essentially the blue question mark period.